# My Function To Count The Largest Binary Gap Doesn't Work But I Can't Figure Out Why

Tags: python, binary

I'm working through the Codility problems and I have gotten the first one almost correct. The task is to write a function which returns the longest binary gap (a sequence of 0s in between 1s) in a binary number. I have gotten all of the test numbers correct apart from 9, which should be 2 (its binary representation is 1001) but which my function returns as 0. I can't seem to figure out why.

My function is as follows:

```
def Solution(N):
  x = bin(N)[2:]
  x_string = str(x)
  y = (len(x_string))
  count = 0
  max = 0
  for index, item in enumerate(x_string):
      if item == "1":
          count = 0
      elif item == "0" and x_string[index + 1:y-1] != "0"*(y -1 - (index + 1)):
          count = count + 1
          if count > max:
              max = count
  print(max)
```

The complicated indexing and second condition in the elif statement is so that when a 0 is not contained between two 1s then it isn't recognised as the beginning of a binary gap e.g. when the for loop looks at the second character in bin(16) = 10000, it doesn't set count to 1 because all of the remaining characters in the string are also zero.

Comment: I think Sam is on the right track. You might have seen different solutions getting popped up here and being deleted, that is because there are more elegant ways into doing this. You might want look at and understand the solutions others provided after you have found the solution yourself. One tip: you can see `max` being in the orange color; that means it is an Python keyword. You should not use it as a variable because now it can nowhere being used again to get the max of two or more numbers. Pay attention to your IDE,  VSCode or PyCharm should have warned you for this.

Comment: Very good suggestions. ^^^   For small program, you can also try to run it in this visual platform to *debug* - https://pythontutor.com/    For this problem, I will do it with *groupby*...

Comment: @AutomatedChaos `max` is not a keyword. And you *can't* use keywords as variable names (except the soft ones, outside their specific contexts).

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution

```
x_string[index + 1:y-1] != "0"
```

this bit wants to take a look at the whole string that's left, but the end argument isn't inclusive,it's exluded, so if string length = 4; string[0:4] is the whole string.

source: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html

-Sam

Comment: Hi Sam, 

thanks so much! 

When I change that part of the elif statement to "x_string[index + 1:y] != "0"*(y - (index + 1))" then the function returns the right answer for all of my test cases.